# List view height return zero only for first item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listitem

I am trying to get the list view heigh at run time to fit the item to height of screen.

Here is my code: in my `getView()`

```
int totalHeight = activity.getListView().getHeight();
            int rowHeight = totalHeight / getCount(); // Divide by number of items.
            activity.getListView().setScrollContainer(false);
            activity.getListView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            convertView.setMinimumHeight(rowHeight);
```

In my activity i have programatically created List View with both width and height as MATCH_PARENT.

But i tried to debug and saw that only for the first item the list view height is 0 but for rest of the items its giving me proper height.

Why so
? how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most probably due to that the view has not been created yet. In this situation the height would be 0.

You can get the height of the view using something like:

```
final ListView listView = activity.getListView();
ViewTreeObserver vto = listView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int totalHeight = listView.getHeight();
        int rowHeight = totalHeight / getCount(); // Divide by number of items.
        listView.setScrollContainer(false);
        listView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        convertView.setMinimumHeight(rowHeight);

        ViewTreeObserver obs = listView.getViewTreeObserver();    
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }

});
```

The reason for checking the `Build.VERSION` is that in the SDK prior to Jelly Bean the name of the method was different (OnGlobalLayout vs GlobalOnLayout)

Comment: Where do i need to add this  ? inside getView()

Comment: what is tv here ? and why this if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) here ? and also i cannot set convertview inside the onGlobalLayout

Comment: are you doing this in a fragment or an activity?

Comment: I have a inner class as adapter, i am i am using this list in FragmentActity

Comment: Depends on what you want to accomplish. You can put this on your onCreate if it is after you have inflated the view

Comment: i am getting these errors JELLY_BEAN cannot be resolved or is not a field, and also The method removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){}) is undefined for the type ViewTreeObserver

Comment: Which android are you targeting? What do you have in your AndroidManifest for android:targetSdkVersion

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46905/discussion-between-maclir-and-user2056563)

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because when the `getView` for the first item was called the height of the `listview` is not determined.

you need to use `ViewTreeObserver` to give you an event for layout change and in that you can get the height.